# How to store images in sqlite database and display them?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application I need to display questions along with images in Android. I have stored questions in sqlite db and displaying them. I have created a folder DBimages in assets folder. Now all my images are there in DBimages folder.

I have created two classes. I am able to display the question and options from local sqlite db but I am unable to display the image which is stored in `assets\DBimages\abc.png`.

The names of all the images are stored in pictures column in sqlite db table. But how to display the image related to that particular question. Please help me regarding this.

**UserBO.java**

```
public String getQuestion() {
return question;
}
public void setQuestion(String question) {
this.question = question;
}
public String getImage() {
return pictures;
}

public void setImage(String pictures) {
this.pictures = pictures;
}
```

**Select.java**

```
ArrayList<UserBO> usersList = new ArrayList<UserBO>();
for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
ArrayList<String> list = stringList.get(i);
UserBO user = new UserBO();
try {
user.id = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
user.name = list.get(2);
user.question = list.get(3);
user.option1 = list.get(4);
user.option2 = list.get(5);
user.option3 = list.get(6);
user.option4 = list.get(7);
user.option5 = list.get(8);
user.pictures = list.get(9);
user.answer = (list.get(10));
} 
catch (Exception e){}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
View view = convertView;
try{
if (view == null) {
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); 
}
final UserBO listItem = mList.get(position);                
if (listItem != null) {
( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_question) ).setText( listItem.getQuestion()+"");
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.f);
( (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option1) ).setText( listItem.getOption1() );
( (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option2) ).setText( listItem.getOption2()+"" );
( (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option3) ).setText( listItem.getOption3()+"" );
( (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option4) ).setText( listItem.getOption4()+"" );
( (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.option5) ).setText( listItem.getOption5()+"" );
}}catch(Exception e){}
return view;
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ugly way, to store images in SQLite database. **Just store images in sdcard and save the relevant path of those images in SQLite database.**

```
In your need, put the images in either drawable folder or in asset folder then store its
name(with question ID or number also) in SQLite and use it in application.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the respone. I kept my images in drawable folder. Now I need to get the img path and the image name from sqlite db image column. Could you please give an example for this with sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are storing the images in drawable folder then I don't think so you have to store it in your database file, just rename image as a question id or name and use directly it from the drawable.

Comment: for example. save one image with name question1 in drawable folder, now you get data for question 1 from your sqlite database, then from cursor's index if question is 1 then set, ex: ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.question1);

Comment: Hi I need to store more than 1000 images. So in this case what should I do?

Comment: If you store 1000 images on SQLIte databse or in any directory of your app, your app size is being larger.

Comment: Is there any other alternative for this issue?

Comment: If possible, you can put those images on server and at display time just download particular image and display it.

Comment: Hi at present I am saving the questions in local sqlite db. And as you said I will put those images in server. How can I display the image along with each question? Please help me regarding this.

Comment: just store image's server uri with question and when you have to load that question just fetch uri of image to and from that uri make http call and download that image from server then you can display it. And first of all if you think the given above answer is useful for you then please mark as a correct answer. (right symbol below voting button) it will help you also and other user to,