# Saving an image on sqlite from camera or gallery

Tags: android, image, sqlite, camera, imageview

I am struggling with saving image on sqlite.
I am trying to save image as blob on sqlite.
I don't know how to declare `imageView` to `byte[]` because I am using insert method on `dbAdapter`.
Is it good way to save the image into database? some people said that saving file path url into database is better. If it is better, please give me some your hands.
I am really getting tough for that.
Many thanks.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
       switch (requestCode)
       {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        selectedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage, 200, 250, false);
        selectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
        break;

        case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            mImageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        break;
       }
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
}

private void saveState() 
{
    String name = (String) nameEdit.getText().toString();
    String category = (String) categoryEdit.getText().toString();
    String expired_date = (String) expired_Date_Btn.getText().toString();
    //byte[] image = (byte[]) mImageView... I HAVE TO DO SOME CODING HERE.. 
    if(mRowId == null)
    {
        long id = mDbHelper.insertItem(category, name, expired_date, image);

        if(id>0)
        {
            mRowId = id;
        }           
    }
    else 
    {
        mDbHelper.updateItem(mRowId, category, name, expired_date, image);
    }   
}
```

DbAdapter class

```
    public long insertItem(String category, String name, String expired_date, byte[] image)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EXPIRED_DATE, expired_date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
ConvertDrawableToByteArray(mImageView.getDrawable()
```

With ConvertDrawabelToByteArray defined like this:

```
public static byte[] ConvertDrawableToByteArray(Drawable drawableResource) {

    Bitmap imageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableResource).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream imageByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, imageByteStream);
    byte[] imageByteData = imageByteStream.toByteArray();
    return imageByteData;
}
```

Though I think you should be able to get the bytes out of the Bitmap as well.  All that said, storing the filepath in sql lite would probably be more efficient, however, if the user deletes the image you'd have to handle that in your application.

Comment: Thank you for replying, and it is good for me. However, still my application cannot handle database with image :(

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean it won't handle the image?

Comment: I thought DbAdapter has problem because image column cannot get it. In dbAdapter, I created the image column as blob type. However, sqlite cannot get the blob column at the moment. I don't know what it is problem with. When I run the application, it cannot fetch the item from database. Then I am still struggling with saving image even you gave answer..

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to do the fetch or save?

Comment: Yes. That is my problem.. I cannot solve it. If you can, could you help me? I cannot find where I am doing wrong. If you have a time, could you check the dbAdapter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362574/sqlite-saving-image-as-blob   here is link.. I really getting tough.. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5547/discussion-between-user725505-and-chris)

Answer (score 2):

For your other part of question about camera,this piece of code will be helpfull.

```
buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }
});

myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(this);
readDatabase();
}

protected void newTab(String label, Drawable icon, int page) {
    TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(label);
    tabSpec.setIndicator(label,icon);
    tabSpec.setContent(page);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

// Called when shutter is opened
ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
    }
};

// Handles data for raw picture
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    }
};

// Handles data for jpeg picture
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("image", data);
        db.insert("storedImages", "tag", values);
        preview.camera.startPreview();
    }
};

protected void readDatabase() {
    TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    info.setText("Integer.toString(cursor.getCount())");
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM storedImages ;", null);

    info.setText(Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));

    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
        image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length));
    }
}

}
```

[Have a look at this](http://madskool.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/dr-android-answers-saving-camera-pictures-to-sql-lite/)

Comment: You can check this link for Some usefull suggestion regarding ,what will the better way to save image in SQLite database.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119162/how-to-store-images-in-sqlite-database-and-display-them