# Sqlite saving image as blob

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I am trying to save image as blob type.
I am not sure it is right. When I debugging, fetchAllItems() and fetchItem() is not working.
Is there any mistaken? I cannot find it at all..
Sorry for long coding because I cannot find problem with blob.
Please help me. Thanks..

Error message here.
12-02 20:38:26.291: I/Database(22251): 
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: image

```
public class FridgeDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fridge_db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Database creates through sql statement

    private static final String DATBASE_CREATE = "create table fridge_table " +
            "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + 
            "category text not null, name text not null, "+"" +
            "expired_date text not null, image BLOB);";

    public FridgeDatabaseHelper(Context ctxt)
    {
        //we can put database file name on 'DATABASE_NAME'
        super(ctxt, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    //onCreate method
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        //Method is called during creation of the database
        db.execSQL(DATBASE_CREATE);

    }

//Database fields
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_EXPIRED_DATE = "expired_date";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "fridge_table";

private Context ctxt;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private FridgeDatabaseHelper dbhelper;

//SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");

public FridgeDbAdapter(Context ctxt)
{
    this.ctxt = ctxt;
}

//Open database
public FridgeDbAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    dbhelper = new FridgeDatabaseHelper(ctxt);
    db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//Close database
public void close(){
    dbhelper.close();
}

//Create a new item
public long insertItem(String category, String name, String expired_date, byte[] image)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EXPIRED_DATE, expired_date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//return cursor over the list of all items in the database
public Cursor fetchAllItems(){
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]
                   {KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_NAME, KEY_EXPIRED_DATE, KEY_IMAGE}, 
                   null, null, null, null, null);
}

//return a cursor positioned at the defined item
public Cursor fetchItem(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, 
    new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_NAME, KEY_EXPIRED_DATE, KEY_IMAGE}, 
    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    //byte[] image = null;
    if(mCursor != null){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        //image = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE));
    }
    return mCursor; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this will solve it but try changing BLOB to blob (uppercase to lowercase) in your create statement.

Comment: Oh.. I solved it through updating database. Thanks. However, I got stuck again saving image. When I pick picture from camera, and saved it, list view made two items not only once. First one is still does not show picture, but second one appears selected picture finally, but I cannot modify image at all..

Comment: What did you have to change in updating the database?  When you say you cannot modify the image do you mean how do you update the record in the database?

Comment: Sometimes image is saved but sometimes not. I am really wondering. Can I give my code by email? Could you check it for me? I am really sorry for that. I am getting stressed till now. If you can, could you give your email? Thanks..